# How to sort NSArray with date time values?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` containing date/time `NSStrings` in the following format:

```
2/2/2011 2:46:39 PM
2/4/2011 11:59:47 AM
…
```

where the date is represented as month/day/year.

How do I sort this NSArray making sure the newest date/times are at the top?

Comment: NSString that is being returned from a web service.

Comment: The first field is the month. I'm sorry I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you’re dealing with dates, use `NSDate` instead of `NSString`. Also, it’s important to consider the time zone — does the Web service provide dates in UTC or some other time zone?

You should first convert your array of strings into an array of dates. Otherwise, you’d be converting a string to a date whenever it is used for comparison, and there will be more comparisons than the number of strings.

For example:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];

NSMutableArray *dateArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *dateString in array) {
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    if (date) [dateArray addObject:date];
    // If the date is nil, the string wasn't a valid date.
    // You could add some error reporting in that case.
}
```

This converts `array`, an array of `NSStrings`, to `dateArray`, a mutable array of `NSDates`. The date formatter uses the system time zone. If you want to use UTC as the time zone:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

Having done that, sorting the array is trivial:

```
[dateArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method [compare](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare%3a) to compare two dates,

Sample NSDate comparision,

```
NSDate *dateOne = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2008-12-04 03:00:00 +0900"];
NSDate *dateTwo = [NSDate dateWithString:@"2008-12-04 04:00:00 +0900"];

switch ([dateOne compare:dateTwo]){
case NSOrderedAscending:
NSLog(@”NSOrderedAscending”);
break;
case NSOrderedSame:
NSLog(@”NSOrderedSame”);
break;
case NSOrderedDescending:
NSLog(@”NSOrderedDescending”);
break;
}
```

Use you own logic to sort

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    NSMutableArray *mutArr=[yourArray mutableCopy];//convert your NSArray into mutable array
    NSDateFormatter *df=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorealese];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *compareDate;
NSInteger index;
for(int i=0;i<[mutArray count];i++)
{
    index=i;
    compareDate=[df dateFromString:[mutArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSDate *compareDateSecond;
    for(int j=i+1;j<counter;j++)
    {
        compareDateSecond=[df dateFromString:[mutArr objectAtIndex:j]];
        NSComparisonResult result = [compareDate compare:compareDateSecond];
       if(result == NSOrderedAscending)
       {
           compareDate=compareDateSecond;
           index=j;
       }
    }
    if(i!=index)
      [mutArr exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:index];
}
    }

NSLog(@"%@",mutArr);
```

Comment: Please give some extra effort in typing a comment why this down vote.

Comment: I didn't vote your answer down, but it looks like you're doing something like bubble sort, but since it is only doing one pass, it will not work. Also, bubble sort is very slow. (Note, as is, your code won't compile because dateTwo isn't declared.)

Comment: Even after your edit, the sorting code still doesn’t work. In general, you cannot sort an array in linear time.

Comment: Thanks @Bavarious and @ThomasW, now i think it definitely work.in hurry i had done a mistake.