# How to sort a NSMUtableArray consisting of strings of date/time values?

Tags: objective-c, ios

The NSMutableArray (inboxFaxItems)consists of strings set up like:  MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a
for example: 
2/2/2011 2:46:39 PM
2/4/2011 11:59:47 AM

I need to be able to sort this array so that the newest dates are at the top.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface InboxTableViewController : UITableViewController<NSXMLParserDelegate> {


    //all of these need to be put in custom class
    NSMutableArray *inboxFaxItems;
    NSMutableArray *dateArray;
    NSMutableArray *inboxMessageID;
    NSMutableArray *inboxMessagePageCount;
    NSMutableArray *inboxMessageFrom;



    NSMutableData *xmlData;
    NSURLConnection *connectionInprogress;
    NSMutableString *inboxFaxesString;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

}


-(void) loadInbox;

@end



- (void)dealloc {
    [inboxFaxItems release];
    inboxFaxItems = nil;

    [inboxMessageID release];
    inboxMessageID = nil;

    [inboxMessagePageCount release];
    inboxMessagePageCount = nil;

    [inboxMessageFrom release];
    inboxMessageFrom = nil;

    [dateArray release];
    dateArray = nil;


    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [dateArray count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InboxFaxItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    [[cell textLabel]setText:[dateArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"document.png"];
    return cell;
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{


    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:xmlData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];

    //do sorting here
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"];

    for (NSString *dateString in inboxFaxItems) {
        NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
        if (date) [dateArray addObject:date];
        // If the date is nil, the string wasn't a valid date.
        // You could add some error reporting in that case.
    }

    [[self tableView] reloadData];

    [connectionInprogress release];
    connectionInprogress = nil;

    [xmlData release];
    xmlData = nil;


}
```

However I am getting errors:

```
2011-06-29 02:49:28.782 app[4388:207] -[__NSDate isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d9e090
2011-06-29 02:49:28.784 app[4388:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

OK THIS SEEMS TO HAVE FIXED IT: (UPDATE)

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InboxFaxItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
    NSDate *date = [dateArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSString *dateStr = @"";
    dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

    [[cell textLabel]setText:dateStr];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"document.png"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Where are you sorting? And use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` and `dd` instead of `DD` in the date format. `DD` indicates date of the year and not month. `YYYY` will not always be same as the calendar year. See [`this`](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more.

Comment: The code that actually triggers the error doesn't appear to be included; none of the methods being called here should cause isEqualToString: to be called; except possibly `[[self tableView] reloadData]`, but without the code to setup your table view, it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Deepak  dates I am getting are like: 2/2/2011 2:46:39 PM
2/4/2011 11:59:47 AM. Also please see this question that I asked a few months back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958998/how-to-sort-nsarray-with-date-time-values/5959393#5959393

Comment: @Williham Totland  This is the only place where I am ding anything with a NSDate.

Comment: @jini I just saw your earlier question and tested some of your dates in it against this date format and it isn't working right i.e. the date you're getting isn't proper. Use `@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"` as your date format.

Comment: Where are you sorting `dateArray`? Or you aren't doing it right now?

Comment: @jini: No, this is the only place you are using the *name* `NSDate`. We need to see what happens to the `NSDate` objects down the road. Where's `dateArray` declared? Where is it used?

Comment: @Williham Totland  I have updated the code

Comment: @Deepak I have not sorted it yet but I plan on doing [dateArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:[dateArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
```

`setText:` assumes it gets a string, and as such, when deciding wether or not to update itself, it sends an `isEqualToString:` method to the object it is passed, but **SURPRISE!**: It's an `NSDate` object. Which doesn't respond to that selector, obviously.

What you need to do is to make a string from the date before you pass it to the label, and everything will come up roses.

```
- (NSString *)descriptionWithLocale:(id)locale
```

is probably the correct method for achieving this; but it's possible that

```
- (NSString *)description
```

will do all the relevant locale stuff automagically.

Comment: You were correct. I have updated my code above and things seem to be fine. If you could kindly just take a look at my updated method. I am not too concerned with locales at the moment since the date comes from the server.

Comment: @jini: Looks about right, but if you're not doing anything with the dates other than displaying them; I would advise moving to a more sane date format, like YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS (ISO format). That'll allow simple textual sorting, solving a number of headaches.

Comment: I will bring this up in front of client since they are the ones makin the web services available. thanks again